# How can I run a function in a for loop and manage to save all the different outputs in R?

Tags: r

I have a function called diseaseMutation that needs to be ran on data frame joint2 multiple times, each with different conditions. For instance, three copies of the code would look like the following:

```
Colon <- diseaseMutation(joint2, "Colon/Colorectal Cancer")
Bladder <- diseaseMutation(joint2, "Bladder Cancer")
Lung <- diseaseMutation(joint2, "Lung Cancer")
```

How can I put this function into a for loop for the diseases and save an output that has a name similar to its disease? So far, I tried to initialize the output into a list, but am not sure on how to continue.

```
fullList <- unique(joint2$disease)
listofdfs <- list()
for(i in 1:length(fullList)) {

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is *literally* a purpose and strength of the `*apply` family of functions.

```r
results <- sapply(unique(joint2$disease),
                  function(j) diseaseMutation(joint2, j),
                  simplify = FALSE)
results <- lapply(unique(joint2$disease),
                  function(j) diseaseMutation(joint2, j))
```

The first has the advantage of saving the disease name as the name of each element, and since we've included `simplify=FALSE`, it will still always return a `list`. The second is perhaps code-golf-better but does not include names. They can easily be applied post-run using `names` if needed, but in that case just start with `sapply`.

If you *must* have a `for` loop (and there are times it is justified ... though this doesn't scream out here):

```r
out <- list()
diseases <- unique(joint2$disease)
for (i in seq_along(diseases)) {
  out[i] <- diseaseMutation(joint2, diseases[i])
}

## or a named-variety
for (d in diseases) {
  out[d] <- diseaseMutation(joint2, d)
}
```

Comment: Wow! Thanks, I'm new to R, so this was a good lesson in learning about the apply family.

Comment: I'd also like to ask how to refer to the tables within the list when calling out them out in future functions?

Comment: Do you mean with `names(results)` (from the `sapply` command, not `lapply` here)?

Comment: Yes, that is what I meant.

Comment: do you mind showing an example of how to use the names function postrun with lapply?

Comment: If the input to `lapply` is not named, then the output will also not be named. This is why I specifically say *"from the `sapply` command, not `lapply` here"*. If you do `results <- sapply(..., simplify=FALSE)`, then just do `names(results)`. If you chose instead to do `results <- lapply(unique(joint2$disease), ...)`, then you *must* assign names yourself afterward, perhaps `names(results) <- unique(joint2$disease)`.